# Why screen becames darker when i use 2 monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xubuntu

I have Xubuntu 12.10 and when i try to set 2 monitors if I expand the screen instead of mirroring it, the 2 screens become darker. I don't really know how to explain so I took a print-screen.

[image]

Comment: Do you use DVI or classic VGA cable? I wouldn't be surprised if some cheaper card can't handle the consumption.
Some desktop environments apply desktop settings of second monitor to the first one when connected. (desktop size, brightness and even color schemes)

Comment: can you upload  before and after snaps ?

Comment: give me your xrandr --verbose btw try to see your monitor settings, maybe you have some gamma config.